# How to select only published items in XSLT-Umbraco?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

i have a photo slider,there is next and prev buttons ,and when you click on a button,a pop-up window appears and show the big size of photos.Im using Umbraco,the xslt macro shows the nodes within the Gallery folder.xslt selects "Gallery/Photo" nodes.When i upload a photo,if i dont publish it,the sliders's next/prev buttons dont seem and pop-up dont work.How can i select only published items in Xslt ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this debate has sprung up again. It's not a direct answer to the problem, but should you understand Umbraco a little better ...

**Umbraco & XSLT**

Although Umbraco runs all it's data predominantly from a MS SQL database, it does however cache this data everytime a page is published/unpublished within a "hidden" XML file. It frees up the developer of any direct XML editing and leaves it to Umbraco. However, this makes it easy for a developer to forget or not even know it's there.

The file can be found in either of the following locations, dependant on which version you are using:

`~/App_Data/umbraco.config`
`~/config/umbraco.config`

**The Problem**

The XSLTs run using the `umbraco.config` file as it's XML source. However, this file will only contain published nodes. Unpublished nodes will be removed from the XML completely, so the XSLTs shouldn't be able to access unpublished nodes at all.

I suspect the problem may have to do with something other than unpublished nodes.

Comment: thank you very much for informing me with detailed information.I guess i should solve this problem with changing my JS codes.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and should really be a comment. Also I don't think modifying your JS will solve the problem. It may hide it but not solve it.

Comment: I disagree. It answers the question in the sense of it's not possible to select _only_ published nodes due to the fact that all nodes in `umbraco.config` are published anyway. The rest of the answer provides information leading up to this statement _whilst_ (and not only) addressing some of the comments made in the the original question's comments.

Comment: Your first sentence states 'Its not a direct answer to the problem' and you don't address why he may be having his issue. However, I do agree that clarifying the relevance of the umbraco.config was required. I just think this could be better served as a comment. I haven't marked the question down because it is still useful information.

Comment: Precisely, that's why I didn't say "It's not a direct answer to your _question_", because I feel I answered the question "How can i select only published items in Xslt ?" (in title and in summary of his paragraph). The _problem_ Erdem is having is essentially another question altogether that you cover in more detail in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your XSLT its difficult to guess what you're doing. However as @Goran states, XSLT in Umbraco can only access *published* nodes. This is because the data the XSLT has access to is the cached XML structure found in umbraco.config.

So, what is probably happening is that you actually want to exclude nodes that don't yet have an image assigned (even though the node itself is published).

You can do this using something like:

```
$currentPage//GalleryNode [image != '']
```

This will select all the GalleryNode elements under the current page that have an image property assigned.

If this is the case, you may want to consider making the image property mandatory to prevent any nodes from being published without an image.